# How to sum the values of looping method in java

Tags: java, for-loop, machine-learning

I have this method:

```
double featureOptionEntropy = DTUtility.getOutputEntropyOverFeature(totOutputCt,featureOption1ValueDist.get(outputLabels[0]),featureOption1ValueDist.get(outputLabels[1]));

System.out.println("featureOptionEntropy is " + featureOptionEntropy);
```

I wanto to Sum the `featureOptionEntropy` inside loop which is return the result of it values is use in the next method, my question is how to get the total sum of `featureOptionEntropy` values remember that the returned values of `featureOptionEntropy` method is obtained inside for loop?

My main goal is:

```
totalSumOfFeatureOptionEntropy = featureOptionEntropy(summed the total with itself as much as its iterations inside loop)
```

Please help.

Comment: What kind of looping structure have you tried?

Comment: i've trying for loop but i dont know what is the loop limit comparator belongs with 

`for (int i=0 i< (unknown limit comparator); i++){ //dont know what to write }`

@FredK